# Once again a problem with vue: Update vue from 2.5 to 2.6.8 and [Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm using laravel 5.7 with Vue. I've decided to update Vue from 2.5 to 2.6.8 version, but now every component doesn't work.Before everything worked.
I've created an example project:

**try.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    @include('ricurrent_item.head')
</head>
<body>
<div id="example">
    <example />
</div>


<script src="js/app.js" charset="utf-8" ></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
require('./bootstrap');
const axios =require('axios');

window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.component('example', require("./components/ExampleComponent.vue"));

Tryexample = new Vue({
    el: '#example',
    mounted(){
        console.log("up");
    }
});
```

**ExampleComponent.vue**

```
<template>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
        Vestibulum sed risus id risus laoreet blandit.</p>
</template>
```

Comment: I had the same challenge last night, actually. I went from 2.5 to 2.6.8 and I had a large $nexttick function break. Still trying to figure out what's going on.

Comment: If you make the "Tryexample" a variable does it work?

Comment: No, it doesn't. "Tryexample" is mounted, but the component "example", i think, isn't compiled or anything like this.

Comment: Fine. I've fixed by  adding .default on require.

Answer (score 1):

I feel your pain :) When I updated to Laravel 5.7, I updated all my composer and npm dependencies. Doing so brought many libraries fully up-to-date, including `laravel-mix` to `4.0.15`, `vuejs` to `2.6.10` and so forth.

Unfortunately something changed somewhere in all that infrastructure, causing me the same error you described.

After much digging, I discovered that in Laravel 5.7.19, in [this commit](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/commit/dc58f95ebbf15b8902ccaef4e2aaa6b0ecbb0e96) they added `.default` to the end of `app.js` [line 23](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/v5.7.19/resources/js/app.js#L23).

```php
Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue').default);
```

**tl;dr** Changing my component registrations to include the `.default` fixed the problem for me.

Comment: lol halfway through writing this I discovered your comment to your question above, which basically summarised what I found. Thought I'd post this anyway since I missed your comment earlier.